# Freeze frames in DaVinci Resolve

Tags: davinci-resolve

How can I take a single frame of footage and extend it over several seconds on the timeline?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right click on the clip (or open the Clip menu with the clip selected) and select "Change Clip Speed". A popup will open:

[image: Change Clip Speed popup]

Check the "Freeze frame" check box and then hit "Change". The clip can now be resized and it will only show that frame for its duration.